# HTML audio not stopping on variable count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's a simple program which starts the audio in HTML as variable in `betNo` in javascript starts from 0.

But I am having trouble stopping the audio when variable reaches 10. I have reduced the original code to make it simpler. The counter is necessary for my program so removing it can't be an option. You can see the varible count in the console.

You can use jquery to solve as I am already using it.

Thank you in advance.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var betNo = 0;
  var boxTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('songOne');
    var isPlaying = false;

    function togglePlay() {
      if (isPlaying) {
        myAudio.pause();
      } else {
        myAudio.play();
      }
    };
    myAudio.onplaying = function() {
      isPlaying = true;
    };
    myAudio.onpause = function() {
      isPlaying = false;
    };
    if ((betNo == 0) || (betNo == 10)) {
      togglePlay();
    }
    console.log(betNo);
    betNo++;
    if (betNo >= 20) {
      clearInterval(boxTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="songOne" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
```

Comment: Is your goal to only allow the user to play 10 seconds of the audio file? If so there may be a much easier way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the `except within itself.` part. I am applying an `if` statement. Why is that not working?

Comment: That was my mistake, I misread your code as it's not indented very well. My point stands though - I'm almost certain you can drastically improve this logic. Your issue is because the `isPlaying` variable is always `false`.

Comment: I agree. I am not that familiar with working of HTML audio. I got the code from somewhere, so anything will only help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my answer.
The button to start the timer will allow the sound to be played on safari mobile
The timer doesn't re-declare variables and functions like it did before
You could make it cleaner with less global variables but I don't know how the rest of your code would be affected by this so I didn't change it.

```
<button onclick=start()>start</button>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> <audio id = "songOne" src = "http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload = "auto" > </audio> 
<script>
// declaring variables
var betNo = 0 ;
var myAudio = document . getElementById ( 'songOne' );
var isPlaying =false;
var togglePlay=function(){
if (isPlaying) { 
myAudio . pause (); }
else { 
myAudio . play (); } }; 
myAudio . onplaying = function () { isPlaying = true ;}; 
myAudio . onpause = function () { isPlaying = false ;};
var start=function(){

// setTimer with only the necessary code inside so variables are not being declared more than once
boxTimer = setInterval ( function (){ if (( betNo == 0 )||( betNo == 10 )){ 
togglePlay (betNo); } 
console . log ( betNo ); 
betNo ++; if ( betNo >= 20 ){ 
clearInterval ( boxTimer ); } }, 1000 ); }
</script>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I upvoted it for now, But add it to snippet and add summary of changes and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Also I stil don't know why mine wasn't working. If you figure that out, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler (cause was just a silly mistake). Thanks `@Rory McCrossan` for pointing that out in the comments.

I just took the `var isPlaying = false;` out of the `setInterval` function, otherwise it was being set to false even if the song was playing.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var betNo = 0;
  var isPlaying = false;
  var boxTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('songOne');

    function togglePlay() {
      if (isPlaying) {
        myAudio.pause();
      } else {
        myAudio.play();
      }
    };
    myAudio.onplaying = function() {
      isPlaying = true;
    };
    myAudio.onpause = function() {
      isPlaying = false;
    };
    if ((betNo == 0) || (betNo == 10)) {
      togglePlay();
    }
    console.log(betNo);
    betNo++;
    if (betNo >= 20) {
      clearInterval(boxTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="songOne" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var betNo = 0;
  var boxTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('songOne');
    var isPlaying = false;

    function togglePlay() {
      if (isPlaying) {
        myAudio.pause();
      } else {
        myAudio.play();
      }
    };
    myAudio.onplaying = function() {
      isPlaying = true;
    };
    myAudio.onpause = function() {
      isPlaying = false;
    };
    if ((betNo == 0) || (betNo == 10)) {
      togglePlay();
    }
    console.log(betNo);
    betNo++;
    if (betNo >= 20) {
      clearInterval(boxTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="songOne" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var betNo = 0;
  var boxTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('songOne');
    var isPlaying = false;

    function togglePlay() {
      if (isPlaying) {
        myAudio.pause();
      } else {
        myAudio.play();
      }
    };
    myAudio.onplaying = function() {
      isPlaying = true;
    };
    myAudio.onpause = function() {
      isPlaying = false;
    };
    if ((betNo == 0) || (betNo == 10)) {
      togglePlay();
    }
    console.log(betNo);
    betNo++;
    if (betNo >= 20) {
      clearInterval(boxTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="songOne" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
```